# How to solve Eclipse Team Foundation Server download Mapping Error?

Tags: eclipse, tfs

I'm working on Eclipse Team Foundation Server Explore(TFS), but once I Disconnect Project and delete it(Select delete Contents in the popup dialog),then I download the Project in TFS,it comes a yellow exclamation mark front of the project menu,and it is said  "The selected project is mapped locally to the folder for project  and cannot be imported".But I was sure that My local file isn't exist and it's deleted by me. So I want to know is it a way to remove the mapping? I'm bother to it for I need to create a new workspace while I want to download the project after deleting the project.Thanks for your help.

Comment: It might be a cache issue. You may clear the cache and see if it makes any difference.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg413269.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Team Foundation Server workspace mappings exist both on the server *and* on the client.  "Disconnect Project Permanently" disconnects Team Explorer Everywhere as the source control provider from these Eclipse projects.  It does *not* remove workspace mappings.  Thus, you cannot map new folders into these existing locations.

The "Disconnect Project Permanently" step is unnecessary here, and if you simply delete the projects in Eclipse, Team Explorer Everywhere will unmap the working folders from your workspace.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You say "Disconnect Project Permanently" step is unecessary, but if I don't Disconnect the project and delete the project directly, will the project in TFS be deleted too?Actually,I don't want that happene. I just want to delete the local project and remove the mapping.

Comment: No.  If you delete the project from your Eclipse workspace it will merely remove the working folder mappings and delete it from disk.  The project will remain on the TFS server.

Comment: while you remove mapping , please make sure that if you removed mapping at top level folder because removing mapping only at a folder where actual source is would not work. so, first remove mapping from at top level folder and then you can import the project again.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is you deleted the files directly from folder. you should remove the mapping by following the steps:
- go to **Team Explorer**-> **Source Control** 
- Right click on folder/project you've got before
- Select **Remove Mapping**

Then selected  project could be Imported.

Comment: If I remove the mapping it removes all local files to... great product!

Answer (score 1):

If you have deleted your workplace and now you want to get from some other branch of TFS the error occurs for the folder is already mapped.
To resolve this you can go to Team-> Manage Workspace and click on Edit to see the list of workspaces and from there you can select the workspaces which had been mapped earlier and are causing the issue.

After that try to import again from Eclipse and it would work.

[Screen shot from my Eclipse, manage workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUcki.png)

Answer (score 0):

Below steps resolved the issue

1. Select Team
2. Manage workspaces
   3.Click on Edit,then you will find all Active work spaces
3. Select the path from Source Control Folder
4. Click on Remove button
   Now try to import the project